# Is it possible to fix the orientation of the camera?

Tags: camera, google-camera

I have disabled "Auto-rotate screen", but the camera still changes the orientation depending on how I level it. 
For example, I want a picture like the following:

[image]

Without changing the alignment of my Android phone with the object, the photo orientation may change if I swivel the phone a little bit and get the following:

[image]

Is it possible for me to get the first orientation always?

Comment: Common photo apps always create images upright like your first one. The orientation is usually stored in the exif metadata inside the image. Good photo viewers consider this flag and rotate the image appropriately before displaying it.

Comment: Could you recommend a photo app that always uses the portrait orientation (i.e. when it is in the portrait orientation when it is viewed)?